# Dredd passing trailing square bracket to API

Tags: apiblueprint, dredd

I'm using Dredd to test an API I have written.  It works fine until I try to vary the action uri within a resource.  When I have an action of the form

```
## Retrieve Task [GET /task/{id}]
```

it sends a request to Drakov with the `]` appended. This Drakov server is running the blueprint document.

```
Drakov 0.1.16      Listening on port 8090
[LOG] GET /task/myid]
[LOG] DELETE /task/myid]
[LOG] GET /task/myid]
```

You can see this request has an extra `]` on the end.

This is my blueprint. It is a subset of the example from the [Api Blueprint examples](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/blob/master/examples/12.%20Advanced%20Action.md):

```
FORMAT: 1A

# Advanced Action API
A resource action is – in fact – a state transition. This API example demonstrates an action - state transition - to another resource.

## API Blueprint

# Tasks [/tasks/tasks{?status,priority}]

+ Parameters
    + status  `test` (string)
    + priority `1` (number)

## Retrieve Task [GET /task/{id}]
This is a state transition to another resource

+ Parameters
    + id: `myid` (string)

+ Response 200 (application/json)

        {
            "id": 123,
            "name": "Go to gym",
            "done": false,
            "type": "task"
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your API Blueprint has multiple errors. For instance,

```
+ Parameters
  + status  `test` (string)
  + priority `1` (number)
```

...should be:

```
+ Parameters
  + status: `test` (string)
  + priority: `1` (number)
```

Also, you are defining a resource `Tasks` with URI Template `/tasks/tasks{?status,priority}` and then you are trying to define a `GET` action for the resource with a different URI Template. That is confusing.

I tried to create a sample API Blueprint (saved as `sample-blueprint.md`) like this:

```
FORMAT: 1A

# My API

## Task [/task/{id}]

### Retrieve Task [GET]

+ Parameters
    + id: `123` (string)

+ Response 200 (application/json)

        {
            "id": 123,
            "name": "Go to gym",
            "done": false,
            "type": "task"
        }
```

Then I launched a Drakov server in one terminal like this:

```
drakov -f *.md
```

Then I tried to run Dredd:

```
dredd sample-blueprint.md http://localhost:3000
```

Everything passed correctly:

```
$ dredd sample-blueprint.md http://localhost:3000
info: Beginning Dredd testing...
pass: GET /task/123 duration: 42ms
complete: 1 passing, 0 failing, 0 errors, 0 skipped, 1 total
complete: Tests took 50ms
```

Is this something you originally wanted to achieve?

Comment: Thanks. I should have spotted the typo.  The resource template confusion you mention was present in the example.